# Converting raster pixels to vector cells?

Tags: raster, polygon, vector, saga, pixel

[image]

Is there any way to convert raster pixels to vector cells? 
I mean each pixel to a polygon.

I tried the SAGA tool 'Raster values to points' by choosing cells option instead of nodes option.

As a result, I got polygons but each one is not exactly  on the pixel. When I tried with nodes option, I got points but they are not in the center of the pixel.

Comment: The anchor point of a pixel may be either at the centre of a pixel or at the top-left corner of a pixel. Did you see the latter behavior?

Comment: I updated the post and I added a picture of what I got. I don't understand what is the latter behavior. can you explain what you wanted to say please ???

Comment: The latter alternative means that when pixel is compressed into a point the point is located at the top-left corner of the pixel. But what you have does not seem to suit with either alternatives.

Comment: ook, so do you have any other idea I can try to convert my pixels to cells(polygons)?? thanx

Comment: The right tool seems to be Vector creation - Raster pixels to polygons. Another tool, Raster pixels to points, is placing points into the centre of pixels.

Comment: I found a tool in OpenJump plus; it  is doing it perfectly. I should open the raster image as a Sextante raster image , then use the raster menu -->vectorisation-->créer une grille de polygones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenJUMP PLUS seems to make perfect job with option Raster - Vectorialize - Create Polygon Grid from Raster. User must open the raster image as Sextante raster image. Unfortunately OpenJUMP tends to have problems with opening some kind of images.

[image]

Comment: I just tried it. It is doing it perfectly . thanx

Comment: @Namoat - If this answer solved your question, please upvote and mark it as accepted by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)

Answer (score 2):

I use Global Mapper for this type of conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to classify the raster cells based on the range of values and then run a tool like raster to polygon.