# Converting a raster pixel by pixel to vector cells in Python

Tags: python, raster, polygon, shapely, rasterio

### Problem

Today I needed to **convert raster to a shapefile with rectangular polygons representing each pixel of the raster** in Python, including the pixels with value 0.

---

Related questions:

- [Converting raster pixels to vector cells?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319098/converting-raster-pixels-to-vector-cells) does not consider Python solution.
- [Convert raster to vector based on each pixel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294592/convert-raster-to-vector-create-polygons-based-on-each-pixel?rq=1) offers a solution in SAGA and OpenJUMP
- [How to polygonize raster to shapely polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187877/how-to-polygonize-raster-to-shapely-polygons/) does not polygonize zero pixels and if I understand it correctly, it groups the shapes by values - I explicitly want to have each recangular cell/pixel as a separate feature.

---

### Solution attempt

I could not find an existing solution and so I wrote my own hacky solution using `rasterio`, `shapely`, and `geopandas`.

I am assuming that I know the raster file is in epsg:4326.

First import the libraries

```
import itertools
import rasterio
from shapely.geometry import box
import geopandas as gpd
```

Create rectangles using `shapely`

```
with rasterio.open(sample_raster) as dataset:
    data = dataset.read(1)

    t = dataset.transform

    move_x = t[0]
    # t[4] is negative, as raster start upper left 0,0 and goes down
    # later for steps calculation (ymin=...) we use plus instead of minus
    move_y = t[4]

    height = dataset.height
    width = dataset.width 

    polygons = []
    indices = list(itertools.product(range(width), range(height)))
    for x,y in indices:
        x_min, y_max = t * (x,y)
        x_max = x_min + move_x
        y_min = y_max + move_y
        polygons.append(box(x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max))
```

Extract the data

```
data_list = []
for x,y in indices:
    data_list.append(data[y,x])
```

Combine in a `GeoDataFrame` using `geopandas`

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=data_list, crs={'init':'epsg:4236'}, geometry=polygons, columns=['value'])
```

---

### Question

This is a quick solution and I suspect not ideal. I have two questions

**1) Is this solution correct? Are there some obvious or necessary improvements?**

**2) Is there a quicker / standard way to do this?** Perhaps I have missed some library, or a function.

Comment: Q2 - There is not a standard way to do this.  Raster and vector models are optimised for different types of data, raster tools handle this type of data easily, it is a mammoth task for vector tools.

Comment: Q1 - EPSG:4326 is longitude / latitude, an so is not projected.  This may lead to some very odd effects at larger scales.  For example, the pixels in this CRS are not squares.

Comment: @vinh Q1 sounds very interesting and possibly reveals a hole in my understanding. Could you elaborate on why that is the case, specifically how a 4326 raster pixel isn't a 'square' in lon/lat? I understand it would not be a square if projected, but not why it's not a square/rectangle when represented as a vector in 4326.

Comment: Have a read of this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-can-i-measure-area-from-geographic-coordinates

Comment: @vinh Thanks. I understand that a rectangle of the "same size" in 4326 is actually of different real area depending on its location on earth. I do not see how that relates to representing raster pixels as vector polygons though.

Comment: Does this has to be a Python solution or can you use other software such as QGIS or ArcGIS?

Comment: @MarceloVilla For this question, yes, but if you have another method, definitely please post it [on this related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294592/convert-raster-to-vector-create-polygons-based-on-each-pixel?rq=1)

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.